# RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison, solving

Tags: python, recursion, output

how can i solve this problem:

RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison

thats my code

```
def f(n):

#the conditions
    if n <= 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return f(n-1 + f(n-3))

print(f(5)) #output
```

i want a output for my. code

Comment: `n` is never less than or equal to `0` so it runs forever.

Comment: an how can i solve that problem ? any ideas?

Comment: Reconsider your math.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean `f(n-1) + f(n-3)` instead of `f(n-1 + f(n-3))`?

In the first term, it will terminate as `n` eventually goes to 0. In the second term, `f(n-3)` is within the brackets which have a minimum value of 1 (if it goes to 0) and hence `n-1 + f(n-3)` is never 0 and hence does not terminate.

Comment: I spelled it wrong. it was the first. you are right thanks